# Node.js CSV to JSON - Out of Memory (~1'000'000 records)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, csv

I have a script which converts CSV to JSON, there are approx 1'000'000 records to parse and build JSON objects out of, these objects are then written to a MongoDB database, my script however returns an Out of Memory error at 100000 records unless I pass in the `--max-old-space-size` flag with 10000mb of RAM allocated.

Below is the code, could anybody suggest any modifications to make this script more memory efficient?

```
/*
* @desc Builds JSON from Ofcom CSV source(s) for postcode broadband data
* @author Jacob Clark
*/

var fs          = require("fs");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

/*
* BroadbandData Class Constructor
* @params Array (Object)
*/
function BroadbandData(sources){
    this.sources                = sources;
    this.header                 = ["Postcode(No Spaces)", "Postcode Data Status", "Lines < 2Mbps(Y/N)", "Average Speed/Mbps", "Median Speed/Mbps", "Maximum Speed/Mbps", "NGA Available(Y/N)", "Number of Connections"];
    this.broadbandDataJSON      = [];
    this.mongoDB                = null;
};


/*
* Connect to MongoDB
* @params Function, Object (JSON)
*/
BroadbandData.prototype.connectToMongoDB = function(callback, dataArrays){
    _this = this;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/UKBroadbandCoverageAndSpeed', function(err, db) {
        _this.mongoDB = db;
        callback(dataArrays, _this);
    });
};

/*
* Get data from sources
* @returns Array (Object)
*/
BroadbandData.prototype.getData = function(){
    data = [];
    for(source in this.sources){
        data.push(fs.readFileSync(this.sources[source]).toString().split("\n"));
    }
    return data;
};

/*
* Build JSON from built data arrays
* @params Array (Object), Object
* @returns null
*/
BroadbandData.prototype.buildJSON = function(dataArrays, bd){
    //console.log(this)
    for(array in dataArrays){
        for(datum in dataArrays[array]) {
            postcodeData = dataArrays[array][datum].split(",");

            var tempObj = {};

            for(postcodeDatum in postcodeData){
                key = bd.header[postcodeDatum];
                value = postcodeData[postcodeDatum]

                tempObj[key] = value;

            }

            bd.persist(tempObj, "mongodb"); 

            // Limiting to 202 records for testing - 
            /*
            if(datum == 100)
                break;  
            */
        }


    }
};

/*
* Persistance
* @params Array (Object), String
* @returns null
*/
BroadbandData.prototype.persist = function(obj, source){
    if(source == 'mongodb'){
        var collection = this.mongoDB.collection('data');
        collection.insert(obj, function(err, docs) { 
            if(err) throw(err); 
        })
    }else if(source == 'object'){
        this.broadbandDataJSON.push(obj);
    }
};

var bd = new BroadbandData(["../data/ofcom-uk-fixed-broadband-postcode-level-data-2013/ofcom-part1-fixed-broadband-postcode-level-data-2013.csv", "../data/ofcom-uk-fixed-broadband-postcode-level-data-2013/ofcom-part2-fixed-broadband-postcode-level-data-2013.csv"]);
bd.connectToMongoDB(bd.buildJSON, bd.getData())
```

Comment: Do you save data in memory / array after having it persisted ? `this.broadbandDataJSON.push(obj);` blind guess, this line eats up all the space.

Comment: That line never executes in this case I'm completely pushing the code into Mongo, so nothing is stored within that array.

Comment: Do you read the whole file into memory instead of reading in chunks ?

Comment: In `getData` - `data = [];` you read the whole file into this array. Read it by chunks, e.g. read 1000 values, push em into mongo collection, read another 1000 ...